# Sync CSV files from Dynamic path in Glue Catalog and Glue Py Spark Script

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pyspark, aws-glue

I have stored CSV files in AWS s3 daily basis. Bellow is my S3 file path structure:

```
s3://data-dl/abc/d=2019-09-19/2019-09-19-data.csv
```

In this structure, the date part of the s3 file path will be generated every day.

Now I want to use AWS glue for ETL to ship data from S3 to Redshift. To use this how can I add S3 path in the data catalog? I want to sync recent folders CSV file only.

Also for Job part how can I declare this dynamic path in Glue Pyspark script?

Answer (score 0):

### Populating Glue Catalog

You can create an *external table* in athena partitioned by your date column. Then execute *MSCK repair table* command to update the partition information in the table whenever the new data is added to S3.

This will keep your glue catalog up-to-date with all the latest data.

Reference AWS documentation:

[Create External Table](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/create-table.html)

[MSCK repair table to update partitions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/msck-repair-table.html)

### Reading one day data in Glue ETL

You can create a dynamic frame from catalog in glue using the table created in above step. You can also use "push_down_predicate" parameter to read only one day's record while creating the dynamic frame.

Reference AWS documentation:

[Create dynamic frame from catalog](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame-reader.html#aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame-reader-from_catalog)

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way without ising Athena? Using Athena will cose extra amount.

Comment: You can look into Glue crawler. However, athena doesn't charge for executing DDL commands :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to sync, you dont need etl. You can use `copy` command from redshift to sync. You can run python shell job at scheduled interval or write lambda/sns with s3 event to trigger as soon as all files land in s3.

Comment: I know this is one way, but I have more than 100 sources like that so need a manageable way for ETL.

Comment: Are you using any transformation over 100 sources or are you storing them in 100 tables in redshift?

Comment: Then it is not sync as stated in question. You can use https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-redshift.html to write data to redshift. Or if transformation can be done using pure SQL commands, you can keep raw data sources in glue using crawler over them and then use redshift spectrum/ python shell job to do sql transformation before moving result in redshift table.